# hide windows desktop icon "My computer" in Ruby

Tags: ruby, windows, winapi

I use this script to remove the windows desktop icon "My computer", but the icon is still visible. I have no problem to hide it manually.

```
require 'win32/registry'
keyname= 'Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\HideDesktopIcons\ClassicStartMenu'
access = Win32::Registry::KEY_ALL_ACCESS
Win32::Registry::HKEY_CURRENT_USER.open(keyname, access) do |reg|
  reg.each{|k, v| 
    puts k, v
    reg[k, Win32::Registry::REG_DWORD] = 1
    puts k, v
  }
end
```

I tried refreshing the desktop with this

```
SPI_SETDESKWALLPAPER = 20
SPIF_UPDATEINIFILE = 0x01
SPIF_SENDWININICHANGE = 0x02

systemParametersInfo.call(SPI_SETDESKWALLPAPER, 0, "", SPIF_UPDATEINIFILE | SPIF_SENDWININICHANGE)
```

and that removes the wallpaper immediately but not the icon

Comment: I can't help you with registry manipulation, but I see, that you output the local variable "v" twice without changing it. What's the result if you explicitly re-read / output the registry value?

Comment: you are right, puts reg[k, Win32::Registry::REG_DWORD] gives 1, that mystery is solved, but my main problem is that the icon remains visible, i'll edit the question to focus on that

Comment: Is this a Ruby problem or a Win32 problem? If you make the same Win32 API calls from C, does it do what you want?

Comment: @Alex I'm not a C programmer so i have no idea, i'll add a tag for Win32